# What is Apocalypse's real name?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

Apocalypse is the name given to the lead antagonist of this movie.

> Having just watched the movie, I believe he was never directly called Apocalypse in-universe. At best, the fate that befell those he ruled are likened to the mythical Apocalypse foretold in religious texts. We know the ancient Egyptians chanted his name, but I didn't catch it.

What is the name he was known by to the ancient Egyptians? Is that his real name as opposed to, say, his many "god names"? If it's not, do we know what it is?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56877/who-was-in-the-x-men-days-of-future-past-post-credits-scene

Answer (score 6):

Apocalypse's name is *En Sabah Nur* which is Arabic for "the Morning Light".
From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_%28comics%29) :

> Apocalypse, also known as En Sabah Nur, is a fictional supervillain appearing in American comic books published by Marvel Comics.

Apocalypse was abandoned by his family because of his appearance, so we can assume he had no name until Baal rescued him and named him *En Sabah Nur*

> Because of this [grey skin], his people abandoned him as an infant. He is rescued by Baal of the Sandstormers who sees the child's potential power and will to survive. Baal names him En Sabah Nur (Arabic for "the Morning Light"), which Marvel translates as "The First One".

Comment: He was given an Arabic name during Antiquity?

Comment: @thegreatjedi Egypt was one of the first big empires, so I would rather say Arabic evolved from the ancient Egypt language.

Comment: @Thomas: That's not actually what happened, though. The languages are distantly related, but the Ancient Egyptian language is not a direct ancestor of Arabic. (Ancient Egyptian developed into the Coptic language.)

Comment: @sumelic I am no expert in languages, so thanks for clearing this up. But you say they are related so it still makes sense that the name can be translated from Arabic.

Comment: @thegreatjedi : I see 3 possible explanations : (1) It's a mistake and the writer did not pay attention (most probable)  (2) The words already existed in a previous language, they had not changed until Arabic and the writer knows it. (3) Somebody time traveled to Antiquity

Comment: If it helps, En Sabah Nur is not actually grammatical Arabic, it's a 60s comic writer's attempt to literally translate "The Morning Light" to Arabic without actually asking an Arabic speaker. The actual Arabic would be "Sabah Al-Nur", as attested to by frustrated Arabic speakers in many places on the net.